# how to add checked attribution into input type text with javascript

Tags: javascript, input

HTML

```
<table>
   <th>
     <input type="checkbox" class="wish_all" />
   </th>

   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="checkbox" class="wish_sub" />
      </td>       
     </tr>

     <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" class="wish_sub"/>
      </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

i want to make toggle function as i click '.wish_all', then all 'wish_sub' is checked
this is javascript
i tried two ways

```
    var wishAll = document.querySelector('.wish_all');
    var wishSub = document.querySelectorAll('.wish_sub');
    var wishAllCheck = wishAll.hasAttribute('checked')

wishAll.addEventListener('click', function () {
           if (wishAllCheck === true) {
               wishAllCheck.removeAttribute('checked')
               wishSub.removeAttribute('checked')
           } else {
               wishAllCheck.setAttribute('checked', true)
               wishSub.setAttribute('checked', true)
              
           }
       }); 


   

    wishAll.addEventListener('click', function () {
           if (wishAllCheck === true) {
               wishAllCheck.removeAttribute('checked')
               wishSub.removeAttribute('checked')
           } else {
               wishAllCheck.checked = true;
               wishSub.checked = true;
           }
       });
```

but both are not working. could anyone please let me know what is the problem??

Comment: what is `wishAllCheck` and `wishSub`? Because undefined variables can make a huge mess.

Comment: i just edited js code @Someone_who_likes_SE

Comment: `querySelectorAll` returns multi elements, you have to use loop for multi elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this line:

```
var wishSub = document.querySelectorAll('.wish_sub');
```

Do a quick console.log() and this is what you see:
[image: NodeList]

That's a `NodeList`. You can't `setAttribute` on a `NodeList`, you can only do that on individual elements.

```js
var wishAll = document.querySelector('.wish_all');
var wishSub = document.querySelectorAll('.wish_sub');
var wishAllCheck = wishAll.hasAttribute('checked');

wishAll.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var wishAllCheck = wishAll.checked; // <-- you have to access it within the handler
  if (!wishAllCheck) {
    //wishAllCheck.removeAttribute('checked'); <-- unnecessary as the check automatically removes
    for (var i = 0; i < wishSub.length; i++) {
      wishSub[i].removeAttribute('checked');
    }
  } else {
    //wishAllCheck.setAttribute('checked', true)
    for (var i = 0; i < wishSub.length; i++) {
      wishSub[i].setAttribute('checked', true);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<table>
  <th>
    <input type="checkbox" class="wish_all" />
  </th>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="wish_sub" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" class="wish_sub" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `document.querySelector()` for single element or `document.querySelectorALl()` for multiple elements, iteration is required to access individual elements for multi-elements `NodeList`

```js
document.querySelector('.wish_all').addEventListener('change', function() {
    const checked = this.checked;
    document.querySelectorAll('.wish_sub').forEach(el => {
        el.checked = checked;
    });
});
```

```html
<table>
 <th>
   <input type="checkbox" class="wish_all" />
 </th>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" class="wish_sub" />
  </td>       
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" class="wish_sub"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: "CSS class name cannot be referenced by its name directly"
What do you mean by this?

Comment: my mistake. not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you're setting the attribute "checked" on a list of elements (wishSub) instead of the individual checkboxes. You need a for loop to go through them all and check/uncheck each one.

Here's a codepen I made with a little bit simpler code.
https://codepen.io/nph0613/pen/QWMKQXr

```
var wishAll = document.querySelector('.wish_all');
var wishSub = document.querySelectorAll('.wish_sub');

wishAll.addEventListener('click', function () {
  for (let i=0; i<wishSub.length; i++) {
    wishSub[i].checked = wishAll.checked;
  }
});
```